# Special function or Weierstrass?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration, limits

Given that $f(x)$ is integrable on any $[0,a]$, such that $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=1$

> Prove that: $$\lim_{t\to 0+}\int_0^{\infty}t\text{e}^{-tx}f(x)\text{d}x=1$$

Comment: What does that title mean? Might you replace it with something less obscure, more informative?

Comment: @GerryMyerson : It is a question in Rudin's special function chapter...I dont see anything relevant to that chapter :( eventhough I know a proof

Comment: Ryan, that doesn't answer my questions. Also, Rudin wrote several books.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : His book on Analysis

Comment: @Ryan: Rudin wrote several books about analysis...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $g:z\mapsto\sup\limits_{x\geqslant z}|f(x)-1|$ is finite everywhere and, for every $z$,
$$
\left|\int_0^{+\infty}t\mathrm e^{-tx}f(x)\mathrm dx-1\right|\leqslant(1-\mathrm e^{-tz})\cdot g(0)+\mathrm e^{-tz}\cdot g(z)\leqslant t\cdot z\cdot g(0)+ g(z)
$$
Thus, for every $z$,
$$
\limsup\limits_{t\to0}\ \left|\int_0^{+\infty}t\mathrm e^{-tx}f(x)\mathrm dx-1\right|\leqslant g(z).
$$
Since $g$ has limit $0$ at $+\infty$, the proof is complete.

Comment: So, was that special function, or was it Weierstrass?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why the name of Weierstrass appears on this page eludes me. Sorry.